# how to increase golang.org/x/crypto/ssh verbosity

Tags: go, ssh

i wanted to use golang.org/x/crypto/ssh to write a little program which is able to read the equivalent to ssh -v output. While i am able to connect via the ssh package to my server i have no idea how to enable verbose output or get to the desired information in it. As i am new to golang i am not even able to decide if it is possible at all.

Here is my code so far

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

type SSHClient struct {
    Config *ssh.ClientConfig
    Host   string
    Port   int
}

func main() {
    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "your_user_name",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password("your_password"),
        },
    }

    client := &SSHClient{
        Config: sshConfig,
        Host:   "example.com",
        Port:   22,
    }

    client.test()
    _, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "example.com:22", sshConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to dial: %s", err)
    }

}

func (client *SSHClient) test() {
    fmt.Println("test")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack you can open `$GOPATH/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/mux.go` file, change `const debugMux = false` to `const debugMux = true` and recompile your program.

In order to see the debug logging make your program do something first:

```
s, err := c.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to create session: %s", err)
}
fmt.Println(s.CombinedOutput("hostname"))
```

Comment: thx for your quick response, this sounds like a possible solution but how do i access the now available debug information?

Comment: if you run your program the debug information will be logged on the console.